# Placing objects around image highlights- coco2d /opengl / coregraphics?

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, core-graphics

I would like to extract the white areas/bright areas of an image and place a custom objects in those areas. I need to know which framework to work with. if anyone has done something similar, I would appreciate an answer. I know how to get Pixel values, however the hard part is creating a Bloom/star effect in those highlighted areas.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a mask where the luminance value was above a threshold, then blur or whatever the mask and composite above the image.